# php/mysql - date_format and the time portion

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, phpmyadmin, date-format

Apologies if this has already been answered many times, but I was unable to find the answer and I was flummoxed.

I have a mysql query which seemingly outputs the result I want when I run it in the database - however when I run the query through PHP, it does not output correctly.

In the database, dates are stored like this:

```
2009-08-13T00:00:00
```

What I want to do is NOT display data that is older than todays date. So, in the where clause is do this:

```
        WHERE dateField1 >= DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m-%d') AND dateField2 >= DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

My intention is to strip the time portion, as I was struggling to find a way to convert the time part of now() to midnight.

This seems to work when I run it on PHPMyadmin, but when I run the php script it does not.

Any ideas?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Can you add - or die(mysqli_error($link) to your mysqli_query?

Comment: @Lyndsey - if that solved your problem, please tick the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This seems to work when I run it on PHPMyadmin, but when I run the php script it does not.

You're not using something like `sprintf` to build the string are you? If so, you need to escape the `%` with another `%`

In any case, you can use the function [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

```
WHERE `dateField1` > DATE(NOW())
```

Comment: (She is red faced) Over thinking it again. You are right. Using DATE(NOW()) is considerably easier - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

nickf is right. I agree with that.

In case of using sprintf() function to make a SQL call, you may turn your query into this:

```
  $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE id=%s AND dateField1 >= DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%%Y-%%m-%%d') AND dateField2 >= DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%%Y-%%m-%%d')", $id);
//Then submit $query for SQL query processing...
```

PHP see % as type specifier when using sprintf().

To escape this, you need to add one more % in front of MySQL format string, i.e., %%Y or %%m or %%d. The actual output to MySQL query would become %Y or %m or %d again.